# Node.js, Mongoose strategy pattern with embedded object (inheritance, discriminator)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, inheritance, mongoose, discriminator

Can someone help me with this please ? I would like to use strategy pattern or inheritance / discriminator with mongoose and its embedded objects. I know mongoose support inheritance / discriminator on collection but haven't found any solution for embedded object. Have no idea how to define schema/s or even if it is possible without really heavy coding.

Here is my code.

Sources collection where every source can have one transport of different type. Ideal would be if call of Source.getTransport() returned instance of HttpTransport or FileTransport.

```
[{
     _id: "1......",
     name: 'Source 1',
     enabled: true,
     transport: {
        type: 'Http',
        url: 'http://some.url' 
     } 
},{
     _id: "2......",
     name: 'Source 2',
     enabled: true,
     transport: {
        type: 'File',
        path: '/some/path/here' 
     } 
}]
```

I'm not even sure if mongoose document (like HttpTransport / FileTransport) should contain method read() and do all the heavy job or just leave it as config object and use external factory to create instances of transports passing this config object in it like.

```
var transport = TransportFactory.create(source.getTransport());
```

Or I'm completely wrong and there is other pattern I can use ?

Thank you for any help.